# Cannot create Crypto class org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin

Tags: java, jboss, cxf

I have created a secured cxf web service using eclipse and JBoss WildFly 10.

Then I created a new project using cxf 3.1.4 for testing the secured web service and It's working fine.

Finally I decided to run the client project in a virtual machine that has the same java/eclipse/cxf versions and fails throwing this exception:

> org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Cannot create Crypto class org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
>
> Original Exception was org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Failed to load credentials.
>
> Original Exception was java.io.IOException: exception unwrapping private key - java.security.InvalidKeyException: Illegal key size

Does anybody knows how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to install the unlimited strength security jars, e.g.:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html

Comment: You're right Colm. In my case I have to download JCE8.
Thanks!.