# WSSecurity proper initialization

Tags: java, spring, soap, cryptography, ws-security

I have a problem with WSSecurity configuration in my app. I have all required beans initalized, pointed keystores/truststores etc. Everything works properly when I run it by InteliJ runner(spring boot runner pointing main method) but in case of java -jar on windows it does not work(java -jar on linux works well).

When I run it by java -jar i get an exception in log `Caused by: org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: You must initialize the xml-security library correctly before you use it`

So Ive added `org.apache.xml.security.Init.init();` in my configuration class. Then I get other exception: `Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.apache.wss4j.common.ext.WSSecurityException: Cannot create Crypto class org.apache.wss4j.common.crypto.Merlin`

And there Im stuck... That exception brought me there: [Cannot create Crypto class org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36611154/cannot-create-crypto-class-org-apache-ws-security-components-crypto-merlin)
But I use openjd with unlimited strength policies already set.
Ive tried to put all program arguments which I see in log while running by IJ to -jar option with no result. Any clues?

Comment: Ive found the solution. The problem was fact that there are different classloaders used to load resources from properties when app is runned by IJ runner(AppClassLoader) or -jar(LaunchedURLClassLoader). WSS4j keystore resource is provided in properties with prefix `file:`. When keystore location is set in `CryptoFactoryBean` by method `setKeystoreLocation` such prefix is ommited and one of classloaders from above is able to get it and another not. 
To fix this ive used `setConfiguration` method. Then is set without ommiting `file:` prefix and is available by both classloaders.

Comment: You should answer your own question. Not in a comment, but in a propert answer. And preferably provide some code examples both in the question and in the answer.